# Does a program imply a programmer?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, artificial-intelligence, philosophy-of-computer-science

I propose there are 2 methods with which we could replicate consciousness.

1. A physical replication of the brain where consciousness would emerge from a physical replication of a brains neural network.
2. A simulated replication of the brains neural network with a computer program.

The above list might not be exhaustive please enlighten me if it is not.

I understand this is a hypothetical question as we do not currently have the knowledge to replicate consciousness primarily because we do not know exactly what consciousness is and how it can be modelled.

For the sake of argument we take method 2 as means of replicating consciousness and this replication is indistinguishable from our consciousness. It is self aware and passes the Turing test with 'flying colours'

If that consciousness is indistinguishable from our consciousness would that mean that our consciousness is also programmed?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150915/discussion-on-question-by-8mad0manc8-does-a-program-imply-a-programmer); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 4):

You are suggesting that a phenomenon that may be simulated by a computer program must have a programmer, which is a questionable assumption. For instance, a programmer might write a program to simulate the weather, but that does not mean the weather has a programmer.

Comment: We're trying to create God in our image.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: No.

First of all what even is "a program" in the first place? Like technically a program is just a set of instructions either as human readable format ([source code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code)) or as computer readable formats ([byte code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode)). However what that means is that it is essentially just data. So not only could that data be created by whatever process was able to create that data, it's also functionally useless.

In other words everything and nothing could be a program. Like the chair you are likely sitting upon, when you read that, could encode all the information to build a galaxy or whatnot. Yet the program isn't enough you'd also need a [turing machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine) that can take that specific program as input.

So you can kinda juggle the complexity between the interpreter and the message and both of them can come into being by all sorts of randomness or deliberate action. Relevant xkcd comic: https://xkcd.com/378/

Another problem is whether or not a turing machine can emulate or simulate human-like consciousness, so is it conscious or can it only make people believe it is conscious. So is the book your are reading intelligent or is your intellect just projecting upon dead tree?
And to answer that question we'd need to understand how our consciousness works in the first place, which is still a mystery.

Also just because our consciousness can simulate a turing machine (by building computers or by running through an algorithm in our head), that does not mean in reverse that our consciousness is a turing machine.

But even if it were this would neither prove or disprove a god, designer, programmer or whatnot. It just means that a turing machine could build a turing machine, which is really not all that impressive we know that already. And that there are naturally emerging turing machines, which again isn't all that impressive, we are natural and we build some already.

That would still not answer the question as to whether this is a deliberate act of creation or an evolution from something very simple and what started this chain of events.

And as all of the specifics that could answer this question in a meaningful way are unknown, the answer is as said: no. It won't let us answer that question.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to a century or so of computer science, we have an extremely good idea of what we mean by "computer program" these days.

By the [Curry-Howard correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence), we know that there is a one-to-one correspondence between many interesting type systems and interesting logic systems, and there is a one-to-one correspondence between programs (in those type systems) and proofs (in those logic systems).

Since then, we have discovered that the correspondence [extends](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/rosetta/rose3.pdf) to category theory, topology, and even physics.

So given that every physical process is isomorphic to a computer program, and vice versa, then "the program implies a programmer" seems to only make sense if you already agree that "the physical process implies a creator".

Is that a circular argument? It sounds like one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Programs by definitions are configuration of state of artificial computers, so their programs don't exist unless an agent exists to program them. Or manufacture them. Artificial computers imply computer engineers to design them, etc., etc. Were we to come across a computer in space, and to determine it to have software, then we would infer an agent had programmed it.

Comment: Any plant seed may be seen as a self running programs. Same apply for living organism. More than that, any behavior of any chemical element, is kind of program, that never change, if does not meet conditions.

Comment: @Vitalie Ghelbert I reject the claim that seeds literally compute. I think pan-computational is an abuse of language. There is an analogy to be sure, but it is metaphorical.

Comment: What we know is what we follow. The periodicity of day-night is kind of program, that helped us to know periodicity. Repeatability helped us to define cycling or loops, those we know from programming "for, while, until, etc.". Why so? Because "science of nature is the only significant science". We learn from [Nature.](https://medium.com/@gvitalie/zero-is-odd-or-even-number-9472f489bf94)

Comment: To say it concrete, Nature is the only True [Programmer.](https://medium.com/@gvitalie/zero-is-odd-or-even-number-9472f489bf94)

Comment: @VitalieGhelbert I remember your argument about 'even', at this point. I absolutely encourage you to continue your argumentation. But after a long path, I can only encourage you to see the differences between physical changes and mental changes; the former is physical dynamics and the latter is computation, and never shall the twain meet.

Comment: I think i must understand what You mean. You mean counting "1, 2, 3, ... and 1 + 1 = 2" is human specific. Plants and all other living organisms they do, but they do not count. They have a behavior, but do not express they behavior, like humans do. I understood You correctly? Even so, I am inclined to think, that even they do not say in mind "1, 2, 3, ... and 1 + 1 = 2", they do silently same behavior.